# Powershell v3 Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: rest, powershell, curl

I am attempting to make use of the new invoke-restmethod cmdlet to POST a JSON file and have succesfully done so.  However, I do not receive a response from the webserver like I did when using CURL.  For what I'm trying to accomplish I need to take info from the reposne to the POST and use this for another POST command.

Can someone please explain how I can get the expected response from the server?  Below are the two commands 1st in CURL, 2nd using Invoke-RestMethod.  The curl command will perform the correct POST and return a response.  The Powershell command will perform the correct POST but will not return a response.

Thanks

**edit:** The main thing I believe I am trying to get from ps output is the "response headers" ie. the output below from a curl command

```
 < HTTP/1.1 201 Created
 < Date: Thu, 26 Jul 2012 01:20:06 GMT
 < Server: Apache
 < X-EM7-Implemented-methods: GET,PUT,POST
 < X-Powered-By: ScienceLogic,LLC - EM7 API/Integration Server
 < Location: /ticket/321750
 < X-EM7-status-message: ticket /ticket/321750 added.
 < X-EM7-status-code: CREATED
 < Content-Length: 830
 < Content-Type: application/json
 <
```

**Curl Command**

```
 curl -f -v -s -k --no-sessionid -H X-em7-beautify-response:1 -H content-  type:application/json https://URLHERE --data-binary  @jsonfile.json
```

**Powershell Code**

```
 $cert=New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("certfile.crt")
 $json = Get-Content jsonfile.json
 $cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Credentials"

 Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://URLHERE -Credential $cred -Body $json -Certificate $cert -ContentType application/json -Method POST
```

Comment: The docs say this cmdlet is supposed to send the results automatically down the pipeline unless you also specify `-OutFile path-to-file`. It also claims the cmdlet outputs XmlDocument, HtmlWebResponseObject and string. It clearly seems like this should work. I would try using `-OutFile c:\response.txt` as a potential work-around. If that doesn't work, I'd say it is time to file a bug. BTW, which build of V3 are you using?

Comment: I think I may have stated my question incorrectly.  I am indeed getting output from the powershell command, but I am not getting everything that the curl command outputs.  Most notably the request header.  I will restate my question above.

Comment: What output do you get?  Try running the output through `| Get-Member` to see what type of object you're getting.  Keep in mind that by default, PowerShell doesn't always display all the information that is available on an object.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some fishing around I discovered the cmdlet  `Invoke-WebRequest`.  This cmdlet is basically identical to `Invoke-RestMethod` other than the fact that it returns the headers as well as response.

Comment: Apparently I cant accept my own answer for 2 days.  So see you then :)

Comment: It seems that both $result=Invoke-RestMethod ... and $result=Invoke-WebRequest ..., when used with -OutFile, do not provide the HTTP status code etc in the $result object, It's null in my testing on Win 8.1 PS4. Instead I've dropped -OutFile and checking for $result.StatusCode and then Write-Output $result.ToString | Set-Content $file  (I'm dealing with text so $result.content not needed)