# How to get HTTP status on Invoke-WebRequest/Invoke-RestMethod when using -OutFile parameter?

Tags: rest, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a request to a restful API (Note, it happens both with `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Invoke-RestMethod`):

```
$resp1 = Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile $clusterConfigZipFile -Uri $apiFolder -Body $fileContent -Method 'POST' -Credential $adminCredentials -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Verbose
```

I know it works ok because:

- It downloads a zip file that is correct.
- If I use Fiddler I can see response headers (HTTP 200)
  [image: Capture of Fiddler]

My problem is that code is returning nothing in `$resp1`. I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660194/powershell-v3-invoke-restmethod#comment46652884_11662655) that it is a "feature" when you use `-OutFile`.

Is there anyway to capture response or at least response code it PowerShell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx), use the `-Passthru` parameter if you want the response returned in addition to being written to a file.

> **-OutFile<String>**
>
> Saves the response body in the specified output file. Enter a path and file name. If you omit the path, the default is the current location.
>
> By default, `Invoke-WebRequest` returns the results to the pipeline. To send the results to a file and to the pipeline, use the `Passthru` parameter.